# При переходе через forEach на экран с детальной информацией данные отображаются не корректно

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GridViewModel
@EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel 

ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: viewModel.items) {
                            ForEach(listViewModel.lists.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                ZStack {
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: TasksListView(
                                            indexOfList: index
                                        ),
                                        isActive: $viewModel.isRootLinkActivated
                                    ) {
                                        EmptyView()
                                    }

                                    Button {
                                        if listViewModel.lists[index].isPrivate {
                                            listViewModel.requestBiometricUnlock {
                                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                    viewModel.isRootLinkActivated = true
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            viewModel.isRootLinkActivated = true
                                        }
                                    } label: {
                                        GridRowView(index: index)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }





final class GridViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isAlertPresenting = false
    @Published var isDeleteAlertPresenting = false
    @Published var isGridEditing = false
    @Published var isRootLinkActivated = false

    var textFromAlert = ""
    var selectedIndexForDelete = 0
    
    let items = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
}
```